# How to Handle Disconnections with WsProvider for Persistent Browser Tabs and Safari on IOS?

Tags: polkadot-js, frontend, wss

We're currently working on [Grill. chat] (https://grill.chat)and uses the WsProvider to establish a WebSocket connection with [xSubsocial node](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fxsocial.subsocial.network). However, we are encountering an issue where the WebSocket connection gets intermittently disconnected, particularly when the browser tab remains open for an extended period. This situation significantly hampers the user experience, as it necessitates manually reloading tabs to restore the connection. Furthermore, the problem persists on Mobile Safari and Progressive Web Apps (PWAs) on iOS, without any resolution.

We are using the code:
https://github.com/dappforce/grillchat/blob/ca60e5882e83e3b740baa06fd5ed2061128f8e1d/src/subsocial-query/subsocial/connection.ts#L35